# Помогите оптимизировать JS

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Сделал меню, которое при скролле вверх должно крепиться к экрану.

Сразу пример: http://jsfiddle.net/8bost17n/

И собственно код:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $menu = $('.menu-bar');
var lastCur = 1;
var fixHeader = 'fixed-bar';

$window.on('scroll',function(){
     var cur = $window.scrollTop();
     if(cur<lastCur && cur>80){
          $menu.addClass(fixHeader);
     } else {
          $menu.removeClass(fixHeader);
     }
     //console.log([cur,lastCur]);
     lastCur = cur;
});
```

Так вот, меня немного "накаляют" следующие строчки:

```
     if(cur<lastCur && cur>80){
          $menu.addClass(fixHeader);
     } else {
          $menu.removeClass(fixHeader);
     }
```

Мне кажется, они просаживают fps страницы, т.к., вероятно, там выполняются некие регулярки и манипуляции с DOM.

Есть идеи, как это оптимизировать? Может, сравнивать при помощи `hasClass`? Буду рад хорошим советам. Также интересуют варианты, чтобы оно плавно "выползало" и "заползало" (имею в виду `translateY`) с наименьшими потерями производительности.

Спасибо!

Comment: @Олег Б, вы уже по положенному внутрь console.log должны были увидеть, сколько раз генерируется событие. Используйте throttle, чтобы функция отрабатывало не на каждый вызов события.

что до addClass/removeClass: вот [исходники](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js), вроде без криминала

Comment: Ты имеешь ввиду что-типа:

`$window.on('scroll',function(){ $.throttle(function(){ /* some */}, 300)) });` ?